GuzzleHttp local certificate xrpl-php
Good day! I’ve successfully installed this crypto github repo: https://github.com/AlexanderBuzz/xrpl-php on my local machine and I'm attempting to run example files yet receive the following error messages:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://faucet.altnet.rippletest.net/accounts in C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:276
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(205): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(157): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(64): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(333): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(106): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\hardcastle\xrpl_php\src\Client\JsonRpcClient.php(98): GuzzleHttp\Client->sendAsync()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\hardcastle\xrpl_php\src\Sugar\fundWallet.php(80): Hardcastle\XRPL_PHP\Client\JsonRpcClient->rawRequest()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\hardcastle\xrpl_php\src\Client\JsonRpcClient.php(314): Hardcastle\XRPL_PHP\Sugar\fundWallet()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\hardcastle\xrpl_php\examples\quickstart\1.get-accounts-send-xrp.php(22): Hardcastle\XRPL_PHP\Client\JsonRpcClient->fundWallet()
#14 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 276

Solution Attempt 1: Ensure ‘Guzzle’ is installed on my local machine:

Didn’t work. It’s already there.
Solution Attempt 2:
Place an uncompressed version of https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem in a file called cacert.pem in C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\ and updated my php.ini with
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
& openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem").
Restarted Apache.
Sounded promising as it was a popular fix but didn’t work either.
Solution Attempt 3: Change the code within the example files
As per (ssl certificate issue: unable to get local issuer certificate xampp) - One solution is to change your verification settings to false: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); I tried this at (what I thought was the most appropriate file/spot):
C:\xampp\htdocs\xrp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php
On line 138:
\curl_setopt($resource, \CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

As well well as line 445/446
$conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

The latter worked, however, disabling functions seems like a step backwards. Is what I did good coding practice or is there anything else I could try to resolve this issue properly?
I appreciate your help in advance and I hope I’ve articulated myself in a manner that you can understand.
My specs are as follows:
PHP 8.3.10
Composer version 2.7.8 2024-08-22 15:28:36
Using version ^0.9.4 for hardcastle/xrpl_php
Visual Studio 1.94.2
ApacheFriends XAMPP Version 8.2.12
Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit

You are facing the error most probably because HTTPS/SSL is not enabled on your localhost. Try running your code on a live website/server.
